# How to Add a Widget to Azure DevOps Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

Can someone show me how to add a Widget to the Azure DevOps dashboard from the extension gallery?

When adding a new widget to a dashboard I would initially be presented with the following screen

[image]

From the extensions
[image]

I have added an extension called Sprint Drop Plan.
However, when I search for the Widget from the Add Widget page, see screenshot, it doesn't appear:

[image]

However, the widget does appear in my extensions tab, see image
[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to use the extension within the Dashboard.

Comment: What makes you think it's a dashboard widget? I looked at the extension's page and it appears to be an Azure Boards extension. Also, per the extension's GitHub issues page, it doesn't even work anymore. It hasn't been updated for over 4 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick steps to get started from [the extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yanivsegev.Drop-plan-extension):

1. Navigate to your sprint.
2. Click on the "Drop plan" tab.
3. Start organizing your tasks.

My test screenshot:

[image]

So this extension named Sprint  Drop Plan isn't a dashboard widget. It can only be used in the Sprints page.

If you install a widget extension, you will find it when you add the new widget.